# Component missing admin-side toolbars after upgrading from 2.5 to 3.4

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, upgrade

I'm in the process of migrating my site from Joomla 2.5 to Joomla 3.4. I have noticed that a component I developed does not show its toolbar on the admin side.

I put an `echo 'hello';` in `admin/toolbar.componentname.php`, and the hello does not get called (it does on the 2.5 site). Thus there seems to be something wrong with whatever calls `toolbar.componentname.php`.

There is a [hint](https://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3_and_Joomla_Platform_12.2#Changes_to_Components) that says "In admin components the admin.*.php and toolbar.*.php are not automatically included anymore (this was a Joomla 1.0 legacy feature)." However, it does not say where this should be included. Looking at a stacktrace of the toolbar properly loading in Joomla 2.5 shows that it is being loaded by /libraries/joomla/application/component/helper.php (this component does not use MVC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding

```
require_once( 'toolbar.componentname.php' );
require_once( 'toolbar.componentname.html.php' );
```

to componentname.php was enough to fix this.